# Hyper-V VM - Cannot Access Internet with DHCP but Can With Static

Tags: ip, virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

EDIT: I dropped the default gateway from the DHCP server during a configuration change.

I have a 2016 TP5 VM on a 2016 TP5 Hyper-V host connected to a internal virtual switch, the VM acquires a IPv4 address via DHCP and can resolve and ping internal addresses and hostnames however any attempt to ping an external resource I get the error "PING: transmit failed. General failure." and by extension cannot reach any outside resource but I can access internal ones.

If I set the network interface with the exact same settings that are acquired by DHCP I have no issues, this is the only VM I am currently having the issue on.

I have tried removing and then adding the vNIC and rebooting the VM with no change to the issue.

What is going on?

Comment: That's odd. An internal virtual switch shouldn't have any connectivity to the external physical network, regardless of ip address configuration.

Comment: The virtual switch has no connectivity to any virtual resources, the "inside" resources are on the same virtual switch. All the connectivity to the physical network is handled by a virtual router on the VM host.

Comment: You stated `any attempt to ping an external resource I get the error "PING: transmit failed. General failure." and by extension cannot reach any outside resource but I can access internal ones.` - So is your problem communicating with hosts on the same virtual switch or with external hosts connected to the physical network?

Answer (score 1):

There is not so much moving parts here: type of your network adapter, connectivity type assigned for VM and IP configuration are the main parts.

- Are you sure static IP config is valid and complete (default gateway etc.)?
- Are you sure there is no duplicate IPs in your network?
- Are you sure that your VM adapater has default gateway specified?
- Have you tried explicitly ping using IPv4 or IPv6?
- Does ping 127.0.0.1 / ::1 works fine?

See very similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/662105/no-internet-access-when-using-static-ip
There root cause was missing default gateway.

If I were you I would try to read VM's NIC and then try the same static IP config (providing it is valid one) - may well fix your issue too.

Beyond that it could be something more obscure with more difficult fix. Example: https://thommck.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/fixing-a-failed-hyper-v-guest-network-adapter/

General troubleshooting approach to "PING: Transmit failed. General Failure - Reasons and Solution" error:
http://www.corenetworkz.com/2011/08/ping-transmit-failed-general-failure.html

Comment: I was taking crazy pills, I dropped the default gateway from the DHCP server during a configuration change.